# Automatically create a loop for post ID

Tags: php, posts, loop, query-posts, html

I am having trouble generating a loop for my post. The JS calls the `slide_ID` which then needs to display each `slide-ID` in numeric order for it to work. Example for `slide-1` to scroll to its next slide the `slide_ID` needs to be `slide-2` (this is being controlled by a next button).

The problem is not in the JS but within the loop. I need to populate each post so each post ID number is in numeric order.

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <section id="<?php $x=1; do { echo "slide-$x"; $x++; } while ($x<=1); ?>" class="homeSlide">
        <div class="bcg" 
             data-center="background-position: 50% 0px;" 
             data-top-bottom="background-position: 50% -100px;" 
             data-anchor-target="#<?php $x=1; do { echo "slide-$x"; $x++; } while ($x<=1); ?>">
            <div class="hsContainer">
            <div class="hsContent" data-center="opacity: 1" data-106-top="opacity: 0" data-anchor-target="#<?php $x=1; do { echo "slide-$x"; $x++; } while ($x<=1); ?> h2">
                <h2>Fade out elements before<br />they leave viewport</h2>
                <p>This slide moves background image at a slower speed then the page scroll.</p>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

The loop I am using to display the slide ID number is

```
$x=1; do { echo "slide-$x"; $x++; } while ($x<=1);
```

However, I can not seem to figure out how to change the number automatically when a new post has been submitted.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The Loop" is already a loop, so I don't see the need for your second loop. In fact, the secondary `while` loop shouldn't work because you keep resetting it to 1 for every post. You also have some PHP syntax issues like `$echo` (that's a variable) instead of `echo` and the way you concatenate the number variable with the "slide-" string.

The following [untested snippet] should do what you want:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : 
  /* set $slide_id to "1" for first slide */
  $slide_id = 1;
  while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <section id="<?php echo "slide-" . $slide_id; /* output "slide-{x}" */ ?>" class="homeSlide">
      <div class="bcg" 
        data-center="background-position: 50% 0px;" 
        data-top-bottom="background-position: 50% -100px;" 
        data-anchor-target="#<?php echo "slide-" . $slide_id; /* output "slide-{x}" */ ?>">
      <div class="hsContainer">
      <div class="hsContent" data-center="opacity: 1" data-106-top="opacity: 0" data-anchor-target="#<?php echo "slide-" . $slide_id; // output "slide-{x}" ?> h2">
        <h2>Fade out elements before<br />they leave viewport</h2>
        <p>This slide moves background image at a slower speed then the page scroll.</p>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </section>
    <?php $slide_id++; /* increment $slide_id */?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```